# How to scroll down/up in a Web page without using JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is there any other way to scroll up/down in a web page without using JavaScriptExecutor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can scroll down by using:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

but this will scroll down only once.

but if u want to move to that elemnt, use the below code:

```
WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ur selector"));//u can use By.xpath or By.id here
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(scroll);
actions.perform();
```

this will take u to the element by scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the PageUp and PageDown keys as an alternate:

Syntax: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code as per your requirement:

//Scroll to element using Keys

```
 Actions action = new Actions(dr);  
 action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);  
 Thread.sleep(5000);  
 action.click(driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("XYZ"))).perform();
```

//For scrolling on the page

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {

if(second >=60){
    break;
}
driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

}

//Scroll bottom of the Page:

```
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
 actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
```